# ArrayList to Display Bank Account Information

Tags: java

I need help with having this account list actually display the number, and below the number the actual accounts so far all it does it displays one account with all the fields and says below: accounts found 2 -> i want these displayed

```
public class Accountlist {
   public ArrayList<Account> aList= new ArrayList<Account>();
   int count = 0;

    public void addAccount(Account a1)
    {
        count++;
    }
    public void display(){
        Account a1;
       System.out.println("         "+count+" Accounts Found");

        for(int x=0; x<aList.size();  x++) {   
           a1 =aList.get(x);
           a1.display();
        }  
   }  

     public static void main(String args[]) {

        Customer c1 = new Customer();
        c1.selectDB("3001");
        c1.display();

}
}
```

Comment: What accounts should your code display when you don't add any account to your list? Just increasing the counter won't do anything to your account list.

Comment: [`ArrayList.add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E))

Comment: where is the customer class,what does c1.display implements? and addAccount function is never called in your driver class (inside main method) thus its not increasing the count.Either you have posted incomplete code or you are not clear with the concept

Comment: the accounts that should be displayed are from the database for example i put in customer id and it pulls up all accounts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with this bit of code:

```
public void addAccount(Account a1)
{
    count++;
}
```

Notice that you pass in an account as `a1`, but do nothing with it.  You need to add `a1` to `aList` like so:

```
public void addAccount(Account a1) {
    aList.add(a1);
    count++;
}
```

In fact, `count` is redundant, as you can just use `alist.size()` to get the count of accounts.